# Cannot set focus to input text field on page load event (plain JS)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe, focus, onload

I have an aspx file which loads/run into an iframe and it has an input field in it (a Telerik AutoCompleteBox control). I need that the input text field get the focus after the page finish loading. I tried a few alternatives but it doesn't work. My code:

```
<script>
   function pageLoaded() {
      // I tried the following three alternatives
      document.getElementById('RadAutoCompleteBox1').focus();
      $('#RadAutoCompleteBox1').focus();
      $('#RadAutoCompleteBox1').get(0).focus();
   }
</script>

<body onload="pageLoaded()">
```

Any idea why it's not working?

Comment: Probably you are focusing an element outside of it and not the input. What does `console.log(document.getElementById('RadAutoCompleteBox1'))` show? The input or a div?

Comment: @epascarello You're right It show it as a div. How should I do to focus it in this case?

Comment: `$('#RadAutoCompleteBox1 input').focus();`

Comment: @epascarello it's quite funny... it kind of does the trick... but it doesn't show up the caret cursor. But I figured that if I start typing it IS focused but then it uses the tooltip text as if was part of the input text. I think it may be a control. bug

Comment: It has been years since I use rad controls, but they should have an instance with its methods. Would be something like `document.getElementById("RadAutoCompleteBox1").control.focus();`

Comment: @epascarello I figured that this control has a couple unfixed small bugs. At the end the focus WAS working but it took me a little while to realize that the problem is in the EmptyMessage property (which allows a tip text) causing an unexpected behavior that made me think that it wasn't. Thanks for your help!